# There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced

Tags: postgresql

#### Table: A

```
            columns names
--------------------------
PK varchar |datasource
PK int     |programid
   int     |workspaceid
```

composite pk key of: datasource and programid

#### Table: B

```
             columns names
---------------------------------------
PK varchar | datasource
PK int     | quantitycontractid
   int     | workspaceid
```

composite pk key of: datasource and quantitycontractid

I need to make relationship between those tables but using workspaceid and datasource. So i try as usual:

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relation
FOREIGN KEY (workspaceid, datasource) 
REFERENCES B(workspaceid, datasource)
```

I am getting following error:

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
>   "B"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UNIQUE key` to `B(workspaceid, datasource)` before you consider that as a foreign key in table A. This is to ensure a correct one to one or one to many relationships between the two tables.

```
ALTER TABLE B
ADD CONSTRAINT unq_contraint
UNIQUE KEY (workspaceid, datasource)
```

Comment: hmm but its not like one workspaceid should be part of composite key in one of those tables?

Comment: lol there is already PK created with quantitycontractid and datasource so why to cerate additional unique based on two fields, isnt better to add workspaceid to already existing pk?

Answer (score 0):

The error makes perfect sense to me, your table B doesn't have any unique index or primary key linked to workspaceid. Having said that, your table structure for B looks kinda weird to me. Most databases have a primary key that is an autoincrement and one or more foreign keys linking to other tables. You seem to have made your primary key a combination of multiple foreign keys. While this works, you're gonna have issues like you described and have complicated joins when your query your tables.
Vishal R already answered on how to fix your problem.